# CSS :before adds content after?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

See [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xce56/)

Why is the newly added blue div showing over the paragraph? Isn't `:before` supposed to place it behind the `p` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be no documentation commenting on the z-dimensional position of `:before` and `:after`. And, as @BoltClock points out, they should behave just like normal elements (non-pseudo-elements) in terms of stacking.

Try using `z-index: -1;` on your `:before` segment if you want it behind the paragraph itself. (Basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fDvTk/; applied fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XvYng/)

Code:

```
#example1 p:before{
  /* ... */
  z-index: -1;
}​
```

Comment: This works on that example, but not in my case. It doesn't work in my case because this div is not the bottom-most of the page. See http://jsfiddle.net/xce56/2/

Comment: Pseudo-elements behave just like regular elements within stacking contexts. There's no difference, so anything the spec says about the stacking of regular elements applies to pseudo-elements as well.

Comment: @Cristy Just apply a `z-index` to `#example1` itself, in addition to the `-1`. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XvYng/).

Comment: Oh, don't get it. Z-indexes are relative? I mean, if they were absolute it meant that -1 will show behind all that doesn't have a z-index or has a larger z-index :-/

Comment: @Cristy According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198947/can-i-override-z-index-inheritance-from-parent-element), z-indices are relative to the closest (parent) element. I can't find any documentation to back this up, however, but it seems to be the case pretty consistently.

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers